# Is the Value of Bias and the Value of ME (mean error) the Same?

Tags: r, time-series, accuracy

My attempt to check `accuracy metrics` in time series reveal this revelation to me. The `bias` of the model

```
## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
N10_ar0.8_seed289805 <- arima.sim(n=10, model=list(ar=0.8, order=c(1, 0, 0)), sd=1)
mod <- auto.arima(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, ic="aicc")
fit <- fitted(mod)
forecast::accuracy(fit, N10_ar0.8_seed289805)
##                ME     RMSE       MAE      MPE    MAPE      ACF1 Theil's U
##Test set 0.4763398 1.289879 0.8928214 4.748337 71.5307 0.2324054  1.009128
```

and the `mean error ME`

```
Metrics::bias(N10_ar0.8_seed289805, fit)
##[1] 0.4763398
```

are the same

Is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Metrics/versions/0.1.4/topics/bias) of `Metrics::bias`:

> If a model is unbiased bias(actual, predicted) should be close to
> zero. Bias is calculated by taking the average of `(actual - predicted)`.

which is the *mean error*.